# Solving PDE numerically; getting error NDSolve::ndnco

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm attempting to solve a PDE with initial and boundary conditions numerically, but my code produces a message saying I have an insufficient number of initial conditions. This is indeed false, as I can even solve the PDE with these conditions analytically. The code I'm using is,

```
Clear[nsol];
Clear[t];
nsol = 
  NDSolve[
    {D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {t, 2}], 
     u[x, 0] == x*E^(-x^2), 
     Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, 
     u[0, t] == 0}, 
    u, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

My code is posted in a screenshot below. If anyone can help that'd be great! :)

[image]

Comment: Your conditions could be `u[x, 0] == x*E^(-x^2), Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, 
u[-10, t] == u[10, t] == 0`

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! That doesn't seem to provide a solution either, and I think those boundary conditions may affect my solution if it were to work otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a numerical solution you have to add a boundary condition. Now with `DSolveValue` we get:

```
sol = DSolveValue[{D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {t, 2}],
   u[x, 0] == x*E^(-x^2), Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0,
   u[0, t] == 0},
  u, {x, -10, 10}, {t, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

With a second boundary condition we get;

```
nsol = NDSolve[{D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {t, 2}],
   u[x, 0] == x*E^(-x^2), Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0,
   u[0, t] == u[10, t] == 0},
  u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 12}];

Plot3D[u[x, t] /. nsol, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out! It's very much appreciated, I'm also very thankful that you showed how to get the analytical solution too. Thanks so much for your time :)